# Игра Викторина на сайте.Нужно сделать ведения счета на табло,при правильном ответе +, при неправильном -

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Игра Викторина на сайте.Нужно сделать ведения счета на табло,при правильном ответе +, при неправильном -. Подробное с описанием на картинках...

[http://vokrugit.ru/Викторина/](http://vokrugit.ru/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/) ---- Пример того что уже есть.

[http://vokrugit.ru/Викторина/код.txt](http://vokrugit.ru/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4.txt) ---- Весь код,HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT

[image: Разбор Викторины]

[image: Разбор 2]

Comment: С таким заданием можно на фриланс уже идти. Т

Comment: Может подскажут что учить конкретно... с какими методами или событиями Javascript добиться результата...(:

Comment: Так у вас есть уже идея, теперь стоит придумать логику разложить на мелкие задачи изучить php,mysql и вперёд решать.

Comment: Это просто для себя,в школе с помощью проектора чтобы проводить конкурсы... вопросы,темы,ответы меняю в коде HTML, хотел чтобы счет был виден, думаю функция js сделает это.